# Matching key-value pair without converting to List in KeyValueMap

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

I frequently use this method with `KeyValueMap` in order to match and refer to named parts (ie, "myKey", "myValue")

EDIT: to refer to named parts in the function `f` without an external function definition of `f` - see comments.

`<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> //  KeyValueMap[List /* Replace[{myKey_, myValue_} :> f[myKey, myValue]]]`

> {f["a", 1], f["b", 2]}

Is there a syntax to match the pair without applying `List` or normalizing the `Association`? ( `Normal // ReplaceAll[(myKey_ -> myValue_) :> f[myKey, myValue]]`)?

Comment: Why not just `KeyValueMap[f]@<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>`?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, in order to match and refer to named parts in `f` - eg `myKey <> ToString[myValue]`

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? `KeyValueMap` does access the key-value pair without applying `List` or `Normal` so if @LeonidShifrin comment is not what you seek then further explanation is needed.

Comment: `f[key_, value_] := key <> ToString[value];  
KeyValueMap[f]@<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>` what is not ok here?

Comment: @Kuba, need an inline solution, no external definition, will edit Q.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you need that. p.s. what about `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> // 
 KeyValueMap[Function[{myKey, myValue}, myKey <> ToString[myValue]]]`

Comment: @Kuba, I tagged this as a pattern matching question: often I need to match sub-lists or other structure, which is not as transparent using `Function`.

Comment: Why the votes to close? Nobody has answered the question, everyone jumped on Leonid's response that doesn't address the Q. How can it be rephrased?

Comment: @Kuba, you already mentioned that approach above, but I need pattern matching, typically for structured `Values`, but sometimes also for `Keys`.

Comment: @alancalvitti sorry! that was before I had my second coffee!